# Authorize attribute return 401 even when bearer token (generated by IdentityServer4) is included

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, identityserver4

I have an API written by ASP.NET Core 3.1 which has two Controllers. **token** and **values**. 
token controller get some parameters and generate a token. my token provider is **IdentityServer4** and my grant type is **Resource Owner Password** 
this is my **ConfigureServices**:

```
var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            services
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            });

            services
                .AddIdentity<User, Role>(options => { })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options => { });

            services.AddMvc();

            services
                .AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
                .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication()
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

and my **Configure** method:

```
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer(); //this line contain identityServer4 middleware and UseAuthentication middleware
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(options =>
            {
                options.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
```

and this is my **token** payload (DATA):

```
{
  "nbf": 1607946380,
  "exp": 1607949980,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000", // my project url
  "aud": "UserServices", // my project name
  "client_id": "postman", // my client
  "sub": "1", // subject id
  "auth_time": 1607946380,
  "idp": "local",
  "username": "******", // my claim
  "role": "employee", // my claim
  "firstname": "ali", // my claim
  "lastname": "********", // my claim
  "age": "24", // my claim
  "email": "ali********@hotmail.com", // my claim
  "jti": "330E311687A5F32E8956637A78D5BA70",
  "iat": 1607946380,
  "scope": [
    "UserServices" //my project name
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

now when i pass this token in my request to **values controller**, it gives me a 401 error.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

what is wrong in my code? please help me. thanks.

Comment: My Error Message is:  Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: kid

Comment: You can try to manually add `app.UseAuthentication();` for validating the request credentials, then check if it can work well.